# Ruby regex how to ignore whitespace between digits?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this regex: `/\A\d{8}\z/` how do I ignore any whitespace between the digits?

So that `123 456 78` and `1 2 3 45678` would be valid. Not not just `12345678`

I need to validate a phone number like: `123 456 78` or `12 12 12 12`

Comment: input string please ?

Comment: While `123 456 78` is valid, then why you want to  ignore white spaces ?

Comment: Yes I want to ignore whitespace, where should the x (ignore whitespace) go?

Comment: Question is not clear, as all here assuming, you want to remove white spaces if any. Both the currently posted answers based on the thought, I just mentioned.

Comment: I need to use an regex pattern, I cannot call a method before to remove any whitespace.

Comment: Can you have any number of whitespace between numbers?  I am assuming it is just trying to validate if there are 8 numbers EXACTLY, no more no less.

Comment: The regex now just exactly match 8 digits. I need to match and ignore any whitespace.

Comment: You mean you should check for at-least a `white space` between numbers in order to validate it as a `phone number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the `delete` method like this:

```
str = '123 456 78'
str.delete(' ').match(/\A\d{8}\z/)
# => #<MatchData "12345678">
```

However if you want to use just a single regexp, the following should do, with a slightly different outcome than the solution above:

```
regexp = /\A\s*(?:\d\s*){8}\z/

'123 456 78'.match(regexp)
# => #<MatchData "123 456 78">

'12345678'.match(regexp)
# => #<MatchData "12345678">

' 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 '.match(regexp)
# => #<MatchData " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ">
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are a bit confused. You mention the `/x` modifier in your comment. This modifier ignores the whitespaces *inside the regex*

```
/\d \d \d/x
```

is like

```
/\d\d\d/
```

which means it will catch `123` and *not* `1 2 3`.

This flag is used to enable the writer of the regex to add comments to his regex:

```
/http:\/\/                            # protocol
 \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/ # ip
 \w+\/                                #path
 \w+\.html                            #page
/x
```

To ignore whitespaces of the input you need to add `\s*` to your expression:

```
 /\A(\s*\d){8}\s*\z/
```

Answer (score 1):

This matches both 123 456 78 and 1 2 3 45678

```
/\A(\d(?:\s?)){8}\z/
```

http://rubular.com/r/xS48UYyrSW

More whitespace `123  45678`:

```
/\A(\d(?:\s?)+){8}\z/
```

http://rubular.com/r/i3k8R7yFIK

Comment: does not match `123  45678`

Comment: @UriAgassi OP provide nothing about double space

Comment: "how do I ignore _any_ whitespace between the digits?"

Answer (score 0):

Justt use `.gsub(/\s+/, "")` to remove all the whitespace before using the regex

Answer (score 0):

You could gsub all whitespace like so:

```
"763 236 87".gsub(/\p{Space}/,'')
```

Note: The \p{Space}, unlike \s, makes sure to match any whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/\A(\d\s*){7}\d\z/`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the above solutions sounds OK, you can also try:

```
"123 4 5 678 ".gsub(" ","").match(/\A\d{8}\z/)
```